# Rcpp function always returns the zero matrix

Tags: r, rcpp

I have written a Rcpp function to compute the cosine similarity, between columns of a matrix:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// Below is a simple example of exporting a C++ function to R. You can
// source this function into an R session using the Rcpp::sourceCpp 
// function (or via the Source button on the editor toolbar)

// For more on using Rcpp click the Help button on the editor toolbar

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix mysimil(NumericMatrix X, NumericVector norms) {
  int nrow = X.nrow(), ncol = X.ncol();
  NumericMatrix out(nrow, ncol);

  for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < ncol; j++) {
      out(i,j) <- sum(X(_,i)*X(_,j))/(norms[i]*norms[j]);
      out(j,i) <- out(i,j);
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

The norms argument will contain the norms of each column when calling the function. The output however is always the zero matrix. Can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: Why would this be off-topic? It is a _perfectly valid_ Rcpp question, albeit with a novel newbie error.

Comment: I've totally made the same mistake in the past!

Comment: @hadley: Good to hear I am not alone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warning that `sourceCpp` returns when you compile the code (i.e. `warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]`) suggests that there was a problem with assignment.

Indeed, when assigning values to `out`, you are using the R assignment operator, `<-`, instead of the C/C++ operator `=`. Your `<-` is still valid C++ code and is treated as an inequality (`x <- y` is equivalent to `x < -y`). In this case, your expression asks:

is `out(i,j)` less than `-sum(X(_,i) * X(_,j)) / (norms[i]*norms[j])`?

[(ideone example)](https://ideone.com/TznFPC)

Correct the operator and values should be assigned correctly.

Comment: Oh... thank you very much. The perils of copy paste! I am now wondering why this does not produce an error? Is "<-" defined to be doing something by Rcpp, it doesn't look like a standard C++ operator.

Comment: @passerby51 - `<-` is valid C++ code. I've added an explanation to the post.

Comment: Thanks. That is interesting.